# Why is the sum of all the elements in a Gaussian-distributed list with zero mean not zero?

Tags: normal-distribution, intuition, sum

If I generate a list of elements from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean using Python

```py
List = np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)
```

my intuition (why is obviously wrong) tells me that when we sum all the elements up, the result would be close to zero

```py
np.sum(List) ≃ 0
```

just like the integral of a sine function is zero when we integrate it across one period.

Where does my intuition go wrong?

Comment: Both the sum & the mean of  an iid sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution will have a normal distribution with zero mean. But the variance of the sum will be $n\sigma^2$ and the variance of the mean will be $\sigma^2/n$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the normal distribution being sampled. So the observed sample mean should be closer to zero than the sample sum.

Comment: When you toss a fair coin, the chance of a head is 50%. When you toss it 100 times, the chance of exactly 50 heads is not 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we are simulating $N$ values from a standard normal distribution, as you do. With some notation, we can write this as $X_1, \ldots , X_N \sim N(0, 1)$ (iid).

In this case, the *expected value* of the sum of these values is indeed zero:
$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} 0 = 0$$

However, when you add $N$ standard normal independent random variables, the sum of these terms has an additive variance:
$$\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \text{Var}(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} 1 = N$$

So when you add many terms, the expected value is zero, but the variance is extremely large (and gets larger as you add more and more terms). So in any given simulation, you will find that your sum of simulated data points is very different from zero.

One test you can do is to repeat your process of simulating 500 values, say 10,000 times, and plot a histogram of your simulated sums. You will probably see it centered around zero, with an estimated variance close to 500.

In Python, the test would look like this:

```py
import numpy as np

sum_values = np.empty(10000)
for i in range(10000):
    sim_values = np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)
    sum_values[i] = np.sum(sim_values)

sum_values.mean()
sum_values.var()
```

Comment: That is what I also said in my comment except I discussed it for arbitrary values of the variance $\sigma^2$ and not just the value 1.

Comment: In addition to this very nice answer, it might be useful to point OP towards the name of the phenomenon being simulated: it's a random walk.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition isn't too bad! In a certain sense, you should indeed *expect* `np.sum(List)=0`. More precisely, this sum's mean is zero since the expectation is linear. However, as you note, this is often not the case because this sum's variance is quite large.

Suppose you take $n$ samples of IID standard Gaussians (mean 0, variance 1 in your code). In that case, the standard deviation is equal to $\sqrt{n}$ (and in the more general case where the Gaussians have variance $\sigma^2$ the standard deviation goes as $\sqrt{n} \sigma$). Using the handy [68-95-99.7 Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) for Gaussian distributions (since the sum of Gaussians is still Gaussian), we can see that when $n=500$ about $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time the absolute value of `np.sum(List)` should be greater than $\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{500} = 22$.

To "correct" this behavior, i.e., to ensure that the sum stays "close" to its mean, we have to bring down its variance by dividing the sum by $n$ (or equivalently multiplying the sum by $\frac{1}{n}$). We are then [guaranteed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) that the scaled sum will stay close to its mean value, in this case 0. This is related to your point that the integral of a sine function is zero when integrated across a period. Recall that when you integrate a function, you're not just summing its values over a specific region; first, you must "multiply" it by an infinitesimal area $dx$ (speaking roughly). Here you can think about the $\frac{1}{n}$ factor as the "discrete" version of the infinitesimal. This is made rigorous by the field of [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), where the factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ is called the "[empirical measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_measure)"